# How to update table size from it's actors?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to make a table that has it's pref size and centers itself in screen. When I change the content of the `Label` in the table, I want the table to react and contain all of it. However it's not working, the table is not resized and the label itself has a big offset.

This method is located inside my class extending `Table`.

```
public void setMessage(String text)
{
    Label label = (Label)getCells().get(0).getActor();

    label.setText(text);

    //desperate attempts starts here
    label.layout(); 
    label.invalidateHierarchy();
    label.invalidate();
    label.setWidth(label.getPrefWidth());
    label.setHeight(label.getPrefHeight());
    layout();
    invalidate();
    invalidateHierarchy(); 
    //desperate attempts ends here

    setWidth(max(getPrefWidth(), 300));
    setHeight(max(getPrefHeight(), 100));
    setX(1600f / 2f - getWidth() / 2f);
    setY(900f / 2f - getHeight() / 2f);
}
```

The result look like this:

[image: Result]

The table itself is screen centered.

**EDIT**:
Here's the code of the constructor. (By the way, I know scene2d already has a Dialog class but I wasn't aware at the time of creation and would like to finish this one.)

```
public Dialog(String message, Skin skin, Button... buttons)
{
    super(skin);

    setBackground("grayBG");

    add(message).colspan(buttons.length).pad(20f);
    row();

    for(Button button : buttons)
        add(button).minWidth(50f).padLeft(50f).padRight(50f).padBottom(20f).center();

    setVisible(false);
    setWidth(max(getPrefWidth(), 300));
    setHeight(max(getPrefHeight(), 100));
    setX(1600f / 2f - getWidth() / 2f);
    setY(900f / 2f - getHeight() / 2f);
}
```

**EDIT2**:

I found out by debugging that `label.setWidth(label.getPrefWidth())` works as intended and setting the cell's width with the `width()` method also works. What does not work is the Table `getPrefWidth()` method which doesn't return the wanted value.

Comment: Can you show your code where you add all the widgets and cells to the table? Also, do you want this label to wrap at a certain max width?

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, I just want the box to get wider. I would like to eventually input a newline `\n` myself but I want to fix it's width for now. Added code of constructor